# Unable to insert yyyy-mm-ddThh24:mi:ss.fffZ date format in oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timestamp

I have date format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FFFZ`. I want to store it in Oracle timestamp field but unable to store it.

Below are queries:

```
create table checkTimeStamp(dateCol TIMESTAMP)

insert into checkTimeStamp values(To_date('2019-03-30T07:53:00.000Z'))
```

Please help me to resolve above problem.

Comment: When inserting are you receiving any error? like `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`. If so, please share.

Comment: Yes I am getting following error message.ORA-01861:Iiteral does not match format string

Comment: You are using the to_date function, which converts a character string to a DATE, but you want to convert it to a TIMESTAMP.  What's more you don't provide a format mask, so TO_DATE uses the default of the current (system or session) setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  But that only allows for date/time down to the second, so there is no way NLS_DATE_FORMAT can match a string representation of a TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_timestamp` function instead of `to_date` as

```
to_timestamp('2019-03-30T07:53:00.000Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/WORE7257)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, It's working.